# Same JSF session for same user account in different browsers sessions?

Tags: java, jsf, session, jsf-2, jsf-2.2

When I authenticate to my JSF app as an authenticated user via different browsers,  different user sessions are maintained by JSF for me even when I am authenticating with a single user account.

Is there any way to avoid this & use just a single `session` instance on server for all concurrent different browsers sessions whenever using same user account ?

## Edit:

What about storing the user session data in application scope, so that it can be made available more globally for different browsers sessions)  & using a **`PreDestroy`** method on a session scoped bean to destroy the user session data in application scope (so that it has same lifetime as that of **`@SessionScoped`** data) ?

I would maintain a map **`<userId, userSessionInstance>`** in application scope, for all currently authenticated users to my app. So it would allow me to check when creating session  for a user if an instance is already available, in application scope.

Comment: maybe are you using some singleton objects?

Comment: Just a note: if you find some way to do what you want, don't store a reference to the session in your map; store a WeakReference to the session in your map so the server is free to do with it what it wants without you interfering by maintaining active references.

Answer (score -1):

No. Different browsers => different sesssions. The browsers have zero awareness of each other's cookies.

Comment: I understand this, but can't this be done at server level ?, I mean user sessions for same userIds could be just one, I guess this is not easily configurable in JSF so should I store the authenticated user data in app scope so that it is more globally available using a custom lookup implementation & clean up session data from app scope using predestroy on session scoped beans, as suggested in the question **edit** section.